# I am getting No operations provided in the Spec for the below code

Tags: node.js, swagger, swagger-ui

The below is the basic code I have written in app.js for my backend application. in the swagger UI page I am getting No operations defined in spec.

```
const express = require('express');
const app = express();
const bodyParser = require('body-parser');
const mongoose = require('./configurations/databaseConfig.js')
const authRoutes = require('./routes/routes.js');

const swaggerUI = require("swagger-ui-express");
const swaggerJSDoc = require("swagger-jsdoc");

const options = {
    definition: {
        openapi: '3.1.0',
        info: {
            title: 'Intern Student Portal Backend',
            version: '1.0.0',
        },
        servers: [
            {
                url: 'http://localhost:3000/', 
            },
        ],
    },
    apis: [
        './routes/routes.js',
        './app.js'
    ],
};

const swaggerSpec = swaggerJSDoc(options);
app.use('/api-docs',swaggerUI.serve,swaggerUI.setup(swaggerSpec));


/**
 * @swagger
 * /dummy-api:
 *  get:
 *      summary: this is just a dummy api used to test swagger
 *      description: this is just a dummy API
 *      parameters: 
 *              none
 *      responses:
 *          200:
 *              description: to test post method 
 */
app.get("/dummy-api",(req,res)=>{
    res.send("it's a dummy api");
})


app.use('/', authRoutes);

const PORT = process.env.PORT || 3000;

app.listen(PORT, () => {
    console.log(`Listening to port ${PORT}`);
});
```

I tried everything in the options but nothing is working. I am getting "No operations defined in the swagger spec" error. I am stuck